# What determines the DOM ("window" global) a JavaScript function sees?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

Our web platform uses IFrames to host child windows in a desktop type setting. Because they're hosted on the same url, these DOMs can communicate with each other. However, I'm seeing strange cases where a call to a function from within one of the child windows is switching to the global DOM and I'm trying to figure out what determines what the `window` global will point to.

I would assume it's whatever DOM the object in question was created under, <strike>but that doesn't appear to be the case here because I'm calling a function on an object created in the child DOM, but it is executing within the context of the parent (global) DOM.</strike>

I am using `window === window.top` to determine if the current context is a child DOM or the top-level DOM, and can track exactly at what point a call switches to a different DOM, but I can't figure out what is causing this change in DOM context.

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example? I'm not sure whether I fully understand the problem.

Comment: Maybe it's the `window` that the function in question was defined in? This would make some sense if functions close over globals lexically instead of doing some sort of lookup chain.

Comment: Actually after some investigating I think the object was in fact created in another DOM so my assumption may be correct after all.

Comment: To add to your confusion, there is a difference between `window` and the anonymous `global object.`  The global object contains a property called `window` that points to itself.  However -- objects created in an iframe will refer to the iframe's global object.  This is why checking instances and inheritance fails.